# How can I send me parameter to the front in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to send my `int x` to the front, after clicking submit input, but it is giving me **errors 404 not found.**

Here is my Thymeleaf page with submit input:

```html
<form  th:action="@{/timetracking/compensatory/make-zero}" method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p>Events<span th:text="${login}">Stopped events</span></p>
```

And my controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/timetracking/compensatory/make-zero",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Model home(Model model ) {
    try {
        int x = employeeEventRepository.setToZero();
        model.addAttribute("login",x);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return model;
}
```

What I am doing wrong here, I have tried so many times, but my button is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your controller isn't returning a page.

If you want to post the same data to the same page, the example might look like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/timetracking/compensatory/make-zero", 
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Model home(Model model) {
    try {
        int x = employeeEventRepository.setToZero();
        model.addAttribute("login", x);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    // Let's say "time-tracking.html" is your html file.
    return "time-tracking.html";
}
```